# How to remote a computer on a router with teamviewer

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I'm a proggrammer, I don't really understand about networking, so forgive me if I am wrong in writing questions.

Here is my story, our office use IP 192.168.3.xxx as IP, but some computer use router so the IP is 192.168.x.xxx, most computer does not have internet computer, so I setting TeamViewer to accept exclusively incomming LAN connection, the problem occured when I want to connect to a computer that behind a router, can someone help me, or is this even possible, or someone have any different solution, use RDP maybe?

Comment: If they are Windows 7 PC's, I'd recommend you use RDP with the Windows remote desktop application. It works by IP, and doesn't need a server connection.

Comment: RDP success connecting from 192.168.7.x (behind router) to 192.168.3.x, but fail when connecting from 192.168.3.x to 192.168.7.x (behind router)